# Delta Lake connector query change data feed entries of the table

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake, trino

Starting from version 408, [Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-408.html#delta-lake-connector) adds support for creating tables with the Trino `change_data_feed_enabled` table property. I am using Trino version 413.

I already have some delta table and data in AWS S3, which is built from using PySpark, with change data feed enabling. When I create the table through Trino Delta connector, I set this property to `True`. When I query the table, it will return the latest image of each record by its defined key. It seems no difference comparing to set this property to `False`.

If you use Spark SQL to read the delta table, you can configure the read option `readChangeFeed` and control the result, which is the latest image or all the historical change log of the data.

How can I write the SQL statement in Trino, such that I can perform the similar reading control just like setting `readChangeFeed` in PySpark?

Example of how I create a table through Trino Delta Lake connector:

```
CREATE TABLE delta.table_collection.table_name (
    id varchar,
    value_1 varchar,
    value_2 integer,
    log_status varchar,
    ts bigint,
) with (
    location = 's3://path/to/table',
    checkpoint_interval = 7,
    change_data_feed_enabled = true
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version `419`, Trino enable to read the CDF of delta table. You can check it [here](https://trino.io/docs/419/connector/delta-lake.html#table-changes).